# F# - using Linq SelectMany on dictionary doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, generics, f#

I expected the two following snippets to both work, but the F# one fails to find an overload for SelectMany

```
//C#
var aaa = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
Func<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>, List<string>> fff = (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> kvp) => kvp.Value;
var bbb = aaa.SelectMany(fff);

//F#
let aaa = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
let fff = Func<_, _>(fun (kvp:KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>) -> kvp.Value)
let bbb = aaa.SelectMany(fff) //Error   FS0041  No overloads match for method 'SelectMany'
```

Does anyone know why? Notice that fff have the same type in both snippets

Comment: Available overloads:
 - (extension) IEnumerable.SelectMany<'TSource,'TResult>(selector: Func<'TSource,IEnumerable<'TResult>>) : IEnumerable<'TResult> // Argument 'selector' doesn't match
 - (extension) IEnumerable.SelectMany<'TSource,'TResult>(selector: Func<'TSource,int,IEnumerable<'TResult>>) : IEnumerable<'TResult> // Argument 'selector' doesn't match

Comment: LINQ is very rare in F# codebase, because there's `Seq` module which allows to do same things with more idiomatic code. Consider using [Seq.collect](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#collect)

Comment: @JL0PD the question is not "how can this be done" but "why does this happen".

Answer (score 2):

It looks like F# requires you to explicitly cast the return type to `IEnumerable<_>`, so this will work:

```
let aaa = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
let fff = Func<_, _>(fun (kvp:KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>) -> kvp.Value :> IEnumerable<_>)
let bbb = aaa.SelectMany(fff)
```

Or, more simply:

```
let aaa = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
let bbb = aaa.SelectMany(fun kvp -> kvp.Value :> IEnumerable<_>)
```

However, as mentioned above, using the `Seq` module instead of LINQ is much more idiomatic in F#.

Answer (score 0):

My question is about "why" not "how". the other answers gave the solution indirectly, however the answer to the original question is like:

" SelectMany expects a function returning IEnumerable<>, while fff returns List<>. C# allows using fff directly by implicitly cast, F# is stricter and requires an explicit cast"